# Statistics for Facebook Event

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull back impressions about a Facebook event, but haven't been able to find much documented. With the REST API, I was able to do an FQL call with something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, impressions FROM stream WHERE source_id=(page_id) AND attachment.fb_object_id=(event_object_id)
```

However, now that I'm changing to the Graph API, that FQL query no longer returns results.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get you! What exactly are you trying to get about the events here? I mean do you want to retrieve the Likes or else !

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the impressions of the wall post pertaining to that event.
(I'm going to edit the question I posted so as to remove that confusion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API here for retrieving the likes, feeds, links, posts, statuses, invited, videos, pictures at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

But its not possible to get the complete stats for a event in one query. You will have to calculate it separately step by step.

Comment: I'm actually trying to retrieve the impressions of the event (as posted in the stream). The event object does not carry that.
Which is why I was trying with a query like this:
SELECT post_id, impressions FROM stream WHERE source_id=(page_id) AND attachment.fb_object_id=(event_object_id)

Comment: I don't think so there's an API call to get the impressions for Posts. But instead you can find the insights for the Posts using Insights tool.

Comment: It is possibly to retrieve impressions for a post. 
A normal wall post impressions would be - 
`SELECT post_id, impressions FROM stream WHERE post_id='{0}'`
Previously I was able to retrieve impressions for an event posted to a fan page with this fql 
`SELECT post_id, impressions FROM stream WHERE source_id=(page_id) AND attachment.fb_object_id=(event_object_id)`. 
That query no longer works.
I've also tried using the eid of the event passed in as the post_id, but that also doesn't work.
If there is a way to get the post id of the event, that would be a solution as well